# itunes connect app icon

Tags: iphone, ios, itunes

i've added a new version of my app to itunes connect. i've noticed that after a while my icon looks different in itunes connect. It has some kind of shadow above the actual icon now and it looks glossy. My Icon looks strange now and i don't know if it will change again or if it will look like this in the app store. When i initially uploaded the icon it had a really bad quality as well (it got a bit better after itunes connect changed it). I don't understand this as well since i've uploaded an 1024x1024 png which looks fine to me.

As an additional question to this, is it possible to change the icon or description after my app has passed the review? Will it trigger a new review or is the review only for the binary i've uploaded.

thx in advance,

kuku

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple adds glossy effect automatically to your application icon. If you want to disable it - check project plist file and add entry:

```
Icon already includes gloss effects: YES
```

No, it's not possible to change application name (the one that users see on their iPhones is embedded into your application), nor application icon without submitting new binary for review.

Comment: What about the shadow? Will it be removed as well ? And how about the rounded corners will it stay?

Comment: Rounded corners will be applied always. You have no way of controlling it. Not sure what do you mean by shadow - is it reflection below the icon? Then it's also mandatory and cant be removed.

Answer (score 0):

Same happened with me when I submit first version of my app. But after i uploaded the binary of app that have check mark **pre-rendered** against **icon** in **project settings**. I get **fixed automatically** after three days. 
So if you have **checked pre-rendered** against icon in **project settings** you need not to worry. It will be fixed soon.

No once your app go in review you can't change icon or info for the same version. You can do it by submitting new version.

Cheers